# Kail Linux Login Problems

Tags: linux, passwords

What do I enter as the Username and password when I boot up Kali Linux for the first time? I have tried everything I can think of but did not work. Thanks, Lake

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation for the default username and password? I also strongly recommend learning the *fundamentals* of linux before diving into kali, especially since they do many things strangely and is not typical of a 'real' linux distro. Maybe you could hack into your Kali system?

Comment: The irony of hacking into an OS made for hacking

Comment: Username: `root`; Password: `toor`

Answer (score 0):

username is root
password is toor